# Obj-C, have a number of tableviews, need to quickly add code to say not data found?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a number of views with UITableViews and I'd like to quickly add code to each so that I can add a row with a simple label saying that there was no data to be shown.

Whats making things a little bit more complicated is that in some cases I'm using custom cells.

I don't want to have to change my populate data array functions, but I can't think of a way to add this feature to a lot of tables quickly.

Can anyone show me what to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` data source method, get the number of rows as normal. Then, if the number is 0, return 1 instead. In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, perform the same test. If there is no data, use a different cell and set it up for your message.

The following example assumes that you have 1 section and that your data is an NSArray instance variable named `theArray` which contains strings.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger num = theArray.count;
    return (num ? num : 1);
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(theArray.count == 0) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Found";
        return cell;
    }
    // Normal processing here
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think that might work, but I also have sections, I`ve added the same code like you have with return to numberOfSectionsInTableView but I must not be handing the array elsewhere. Can you expand your answer to include sections please ?

Comment: To include multiple sections, you just check the section to determine which array to use. What do you mean you "must not be handing the array elsewhere"?